# How to put iOS Magnifying Glass effect on Google Maps (GMSMapKit)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, mapkit

How to put the `UITextView` texting editing Magnifying Glass on the Google Maps `GMSMapView`

For example I have a `GMSMapView` to show my current location 
I want to trigger a overlay Magnifying Glass view when calling delegate methods 
`mapView:didChangeCameraPosition:` and `mapView:willMove:` in `GMSMapViewDelegate`

The purpose is to provide an overlay zooming subView according to the user tapping coordinates (like [github.com/acoomans/iOS-MagnifyingGlass](https://github.com/acoomans/iOS-MagnifyingGlass) did on ImageView)

Please let me know if this is possible for Google Maps for iOS or if iOS `MapKit` can support this kind of customization

Update #2: `mapView.addSubView(mapSubView)` works now. But it pollutes the Main `GMSMapView`

Update #1: I tried `mapView.addSubView`, <strike>it seems does not work for GMSMapView although inherited from UIView</strike>

The intention of below code snippet is to retrieve user's touch point at the map and converts it into `CGPoint` for creating a second `GMSMapView`

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    println("Tapping at (\(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude))")

    // 1. retrieve the user touch position as CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let cameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude, zoom: 20) 

    // 2. convert it into CGPoint
    let screenTouchPoints = mapView.projection.pointForCoordinate(coordinate)

    // 3. set the CGRect for init the mapSubView
    let frame = CGRectMake(screenTouchPoints.x, screenTouchPoints.y, 100, 100)
    mapSubView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(frame, camera: cameraPosition)

    // 4. Finally add to the main Map View
    mapView.addSubview(mapSubView)
}
```

Comment: You can use `GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude:longitude:zoom:` method. Sample code: `mapView.animateToCameraPosition(GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-37.813047, longitude: -72.8561644, zoom:5))`, it will show zooming effect in your mapview.

Comment: I want to add an overlay layer of Magnifying Glass to the Map instead of just change the zooming level

like this but it's for `UIImageView` https://github.com/acoomans/iOS-MagnifyingGlass

Answer (score 0):

It seems plausible with a GMSMapView. Maybe have a second GMSMapView on top of the original(high corner radius to create a circle?) and animate the alpha and scale along with the zoom level within the second map. Do this whenever mapView:didChangeCameraPosition etc is called.

Answer (score 0):

By taking reference to this [Github Project](http://github.com/acoomans/iOS-MagnifyingGlass), GMSMapView can also be magnified by putting the view hierarchy in this way:

View Controller > Magnifying View > The View want to be zoomed

The core rendering mechanism is 

`- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2 );
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, scale, scale);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -touchPoint.x, -touchPoint.y + (self.scaleAtTouchPoint? 0 : self.bounds.size.height/2));
    [self.viewToMagnify.layer renderInContext:context];
}`

`loupe = ACLoupe()
        magnifyingGlass = ACMagnifyingGlass()
        magnifyingView = ACMagnifyingView(frame: self.view.frame)
        magnifyingView.magnifyingGlass = loupe`

`magnifyingView.addSubview(Your_Subview_here)`

by this method the magnifying view can capture current frame context, because Magnifying View is the container of other views so that the capturing can show the current UI situation and zoom by 1.5 times (default scale factor)